# How to add 2 buttons 'add to cart' getting with different data in Prestashop?

Tags: content-management-system, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.6

My product has 2 prices (discount price, old price). I want to add two buttons that add product with different price. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just show old/discounted price for a product use Specific Prices option in Prices tab of a prodct.

Or maybe you want to do that for a bunch of products.
The standard way to do that kind of things in Prestashop is by using price rules. In this case you may need to create a category like Sales/Offers. Assign all products you need to that category in their Association tab. Then go to  Price Rules -> Catalog Price Rules + Add a new condition group (choose category here), create the price rule above based on your needs.